# Is it possible to downgrade Laravel 5.4 to 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

Due to technical reasons I just have to downgrade, mainly because I am more used to 5.2 than the newest version.

Comment: Not easily, you're best off spending 30 minutes and understanding what has changed

Comment: That's not a very good reason to downgrade to an unsupported version, you'd better get used to the new version.

Comment: Has that much changed in 2 minor versions? Genuine question, i havent upgraded past 5.2 yet

Comment: @Steve Yes ! It changed a lot, specially if you jump to 5.4 :) Check: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/releases

Comment: Considering that the ["estimated upgrade time" for 5.3 to 5.4 is 1-2 hours](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0), and the ["estimated upgrade time" fro 5.2 to 5.3 is and estimated 2-3 hours](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade#upgrade-5.4.0), it might be more worth your time to install a fresh 5.2 and then copy your code over instead of downgrading.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To downgrade from 5.4 to 5.2 it will take **A LOT** of time, is much faster and easier to create a new Laravel project.

In case you want to install a specific Laravel version you can create the project with --prefer-dist on console:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel projectname "5.2.*"
```

More info on the docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/installation#installing-laravel

Comment: I would also recommend this route and then move your models, controllers, resources, requests over etc.

Answer (score 1):

since [laravel 5.4.x](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.4.0/composer.json) require specific version of php :

```
...
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
...
```

and [laravel 5.2.x](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v5.2.0/composer.json) require a lower version of php

```
...
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
...
```

and according to [the major changes](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.php) between php 5.5.x and php 5.6.x

which may be used in laravel 5.4 , it will be not wise to downgrade .

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is by changing the value of the Laravel version inside the composer file to the one one you want. 
This solved my problem as fast as possible

Comment: While this works (it's just helped me do this at the start of my project) it's worth noting that those later on the development cycle will probably run into issues the bigger the downgrade gets and the further along you are.